# Huawei device pairing with Mac

Tags: macbook-pro, software-recommendation, driver, android

I am trying to connect my Huawei phone to my Mac. I get it as a new device and I can see it in the file manager. Now I would like point my Mac to some drivers of this small Huawei device. (I have them as .ini files or as .exe for the full installation package.) The thing is that I am programming for Android and did it easily on Windows (using Mac just for a couple of weeks). In Windows there is a great feature like "find device" and then just point it to .ini driver files. Is there any similar feature in Mac? I have installed some applications on Mac, like Huawei driver, Huawei modem something, also some mobilepartner application, but still nothing. Is there any way I can use the adb to connect to my device?

Answer (score 1):

Your device should "just work" on a Mac. To use adb to connect to your device you do it as usual, meaning you would have to install the android SDK for mac, then enable debugging mode on your phone, and use the Terminal command-line app as you would on the Windows command-line.

Comment: what do you mean with "Terminal command-line app"?

Comment: maybe it is supposed to work, but there is no result. When i do it with windows - i get everything to work, mac - nothing works

Comment: The app labeled "Terminal" in the utilities folder of your applications.

Comment: that is great, but why should I use terminal for adb?

Comment: isn't adb a command-line tool? so wouldn't you need a command-line interface (terminal) to use it to connect to your device?